# Does the product of N independent poisson distributions approach a gaussian distribution as N becomes large?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

This paper I'm reading claims that the answer to my question is yes, but I'm having trouble finding another source.

[image]

I know that a poisson distribution tends to a normal distribution as the mean becomes large, and that the product of independent poissons has a mean equal to the product of the independent poisson means, which could become large as N becomes large, but I don't think the product of poissons is itself poisson so I'm not sure the using the normal limit is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the question in title: no.

The product of positive variables tend to converge to [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), since in log space we have central limit theorem. However, that is not the case for Poisson distribution, because it always has a finite probability of zero. So as the $N\to\infty$  the probability that one of the multiplicants is zero and this nullifies the whole product goes to $1$.

However, the paper states something different. It's not about convergence of Poisson distributions, it's about the convergence of posteriors, which is Gamma-distribution. And it's not about multiplication of random variables, but rather multiplication of distributions (otherwise you would have seen a lot of convolutions).

Comment: Marked as answered due to answering what I actually asked. While I've got your attention, do you know any sources I could use to find the mean & variance of the gaussian that results from multiplying gamma distributions with given means and variances?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/GammaNormal1.pdf) what you want?

Comment: That is what I asked for, yes. Looking at it though, I'm realizing I asked the wrong question (again). What I really want is the mapping from the poisson means to the gaussian mean & variance in the segment of the paper referenced in my original question. As in, what are the mean & variance of the converged-to gaussian as a function of the poisson means $f_i(s)$, $i=1...N$